# Problem exporting properly sized STLs with PlotRange

Tags: plotting, export

i've encountered a problem when exporting from `ListPlot3D` in  STL format. I'm trying to use Mathematica to create a potential energy surface from given datapoints (x, y, z) with the intent of doing 3D prnting.

Here is a small example I've put together to explain of my problem.

```
table = 
  Table[
    {x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}], y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}],Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, 
    {1000}];
plot1 = Graphics[ListPlot3D[table]]
plot2 = Graphics[ListPlot3D[table, PlotRange -> {0.5, 1}]]
plot3 = Graphics[ListPlot3D[table,PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 1}}]]
```

Let's say table is my raw data and I want to print `plot3`. but if I export both plot2 and plot3 they give me the same STL, despite their different plot ranges.

```
Export["plot2.stl", plot2]
Export["plot3.stl", plot3]
```

I see no difference between the STLs when importing them.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `PlotRange`only influences the viewport for rendering in the frontend. It does not effect (and is no option) for STL export.